# jasmine testing angular modules with dependencies

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jasmine

This is a rather complex issue so I created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/djdcomByxfT2PJQiu6dx?p=preview) to help illustrate. I have 2 angular modules in a single js file. One (called base) handles the typical application setup. The other (called basePlusCors) has some additional config stuff in it, but no new directives or services, and includes the base module as a dependency. Think of it as "basePlusCors extends base". I am having two problems:

First: In app.js, if I don't comment out line 461 - 473, I get a circular dependency error on the basePlusCors test. Why is that?

Second: This is probably related to the first, but with the above lines commented out, the test still manages to execute the httpInterceptor from the base module. I thought I mocked the base module, why is it running that interceptor? Is there a way to clear out all the angular modules and stuff before executing a block of tests so I can start testing the basePlusCors module with a clean slate?

Comment: Minimum working examples are the most helpful -- it's hard to understand what is going on in your +500 lines of code right off the bat. Also, I do not see an `appStatusService` defined anywhere.

Comment: The appStatusService isn't there, the error you see for that is because it is trying to bootstrap the application on the index page, I just fixed that error. I will see about slimming the example down.

Comment: I've simplified my example so it should be really easy to follow, just look at the console and see the log messages.